# toggle boolean in reducer doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

My initial state like this

```
let initialState = {
    todos: [{
        id: 0,
        completed: false,
        text: 'my first todo'
    }]
}
```

and below is my toggle reducer

```
case 'COMPLETED_TODO': 
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
        todos: state.todos.map(todo => {
            return todo.id === action.id ? 
            Object.assign({}, todo, {completed: !todo.completed}) :
            todo
        })
    })
```

No error, just that the toggle doesn't work, completed is always false after the reducer is triggered. The action.id is passed correctly.

Comment: The code looks good. Not enough information to advice you anything. Put the code on github and share the link.

Comment: what is the type of your action.id? string or number?

Comment: Try just to return `Object.assign({}, todo, {completed: !todo.completed})` first and see if that works.. if not you maybe comparing string to number with ===